# Update service provider client credentials based on request basis ASP.NET Identity (dotnet core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have used ASP.NET identity core for google service providers. Following is the code shown below

```
services
     .AddAuthentication()
     .AddGoogle(o => {
          o.ClientId = "xxx";
          o.ClientSecret = "xx";
          // Tried using this event but no luck it is stuck
          // and not going anywhere
          o.Events.OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = ctx => {
              o.ClientId = "xxx";
              o.ClientSecret = "xxx";
              return Task.CompletedTask;
         };
     });
```

But we would like to change clientId and clientSecret dynamically based on user who request the login page. Can we update clientId and clientSecret on request basis or is it only set on startup.

We see the only alternative is to use original google oauth apis to change clientId and clientSecret. Can we do that using ASP.NET identity itself or any nuget package? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: User will be redirect to identity provide's login page for sign-in ,  how do you know which user before redirect to identity provider ?

Comment: @NanYu User will be visiting the site with some token in the url set by the other application. Based on this token we will decide what type of user he/she is (currently we are using JWT for token encrypt/decrypt)